# Java and string split

Tags: java

split this String using function split. Here is my code:

```
String data= "data^data";
String[] spli = data.split("^");
```

When I try to do that in spli contain only one string. It seems like java dont see "^" in splitting. Do anyone know how can I split this string by letter "^"?

EDIT

SOLVED :P

Comment: With SO you need to mark the answer which is really an answer for your question by clicking mark near to the answer

Comment: Jigar, it's recommended but not required.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because `String.split` takes a regular expression, not a literal string. You have to escape the `^` as it has a different meaning in regex (anchor at the start of a string). So the split would actually be done before the first character, giving you the complete string back unaltered.

You escape a regular expression metacharacter with `\`, which has to be `\\` in Java strings, so

```
data.split("\\^")
```

should work.

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape it because it takes reg-ex

```
\\^
```

Answer (score 3):

Special characters like `^` need to be escaped with `\`

Comment: actually escapped with \\, because of java

Answer (score 2):

This does not work because `.split()` expects its argument to be a regex. "^" has a special meaing in regex and so does not work as you expect. To get it to work, you need to escape it. Use `\\^`.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that `split`'s parameter is a [**regular expression**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum), so "^" means the beginning of a line. So you need to escape to ASCII-^: use the parameter "`\\^`".